# What would happen if I powered a 5 V heater with 6 V?

Tags: voltage, heater, durability

I have 2 mini heater pads (carbon fiber) for gloves that are rated at 5 V. In series they have 6 + 6 = 12 Ω resistance. I have a 6 V power supply (~6.25 V by my last measurements), and I'm planning to use it for the heaters. Like that I have 6 V / 12 Ω = ~0.5 A of current. I have noticed that the resistance dropped a bit (with ~0.3 Ω) when they have heated up a little.

What should I expect to happen, in long term, when I'm running the heaters with 6 V instead of the rated 5 V? Are the heaters breaking because of wattage or because of voltage?

I thought to put 2 SS34 diodes in series, to lower the voltage with 1 V. Is that a good idea?

Comment: "Are the heaters breaking"  That phrasing implies that your heaters **are** breaking -- are they, or are you just anticipating that they might?

Comment: Data sheet for the heater pads are required.

Comment: Are they designed to be operated in series from 5V, or in parallel?  If they're designed to be operated in parallel from 5V then operating them in series from 6.25V means that you're running them at way less than the design voltage, and you're safe as houses (but getting much less heat).

Comment: that's fine, 6v instead of 5v won't wear them out unless they are so hot they smoke. a slight loss of resistence is based on temp, not wear. Adding a diode will get the diode hot instead of the pads, not needed here, and detracts from the goal while posing a burn risk on the tiny package shedding almost a watt.

Comment: @TimWescott I guess everything is breakable (even if its not broken yet), the phrasing is general.

Comment: @Andyaka I wish I have a data sheet. I just bought them online, "5 V" is all I have. The resistance was determined experimentally.

Comment: @TimWescott I have no idea what they are designed for, I have no data sheet. But at series with 500 mA they heat a bit, and that is fine by me. I will reduce the voltage however, because I'm worried of accidents. I'm considering some step down regulator able to sustain 1A of current. These MCP1702-5002 seem nice. I will parallel 5 of them and I'm good to go.

Comment: @dandavis Yes, wasting of power is not nice, I will try a step down regulator or at worst PWM, as TimWescott suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For just about any part, if a 25% increase in voltage makes it break, it's because it's getting hotter and the increased temperature is burning it out.  Pure "breaking due to voltage" would mean that something is arcing over (through air or a dielectric layer) -- that's not going to reliably happen unless you're going 50% or 100% over voltage.

In an ideal resistor, power dissipation goes as \$P = \frac{V^2}{R}\$ -- this is a direct consequence of Ohm's law and the fact that power equals current times voltage.  In your case, the power is going to go up by *more* than that, because the resistance goes down with temperature, increasing the current (and thus power) even more.

You can put those diodes in series with your heating pads, and it'll be easy -- but then they'll be little spot sources of heat which you'll need to manage, and there's a good chance that power will be wasted.

Possibly the easiest way to do this that *doesn't* involve wasting power is to drive them with a PWM generator with a duty cycle of around \$\frac 2 3\$.  This should be easy to do with a 555 timer running off of your same supply, driving a logic-level MOSFET that's rated for 1A or so.  *That* circuit will dissipate some heat, but properly designed, it won't be much.

Answer (score 2):

Carbon has a negative coefficient temperature. So it is logical that resistance will drop as it heats. Don't use a higher voltage than rated.
The two diodes for dropping voltage is a good idea if you don't use another means.
Just choose the right current rating.

Answer (score 1):

If there is 6 V at a heater of 6 Ohm, you get 6 W of electrical and thermal power. One hand with fingers is about 1 % of the total skin surface of a man. If we assume the same power density over the full skin surface, we get about 600 W applied to a man.

A man at rest produces about 70 to 100 W of heat, a man generating 100 W of mechanical power produces about 300 W of heat. If the heaters are small compared to the total surface of a hand, the resulting heat power density could be dangerous to the skin.

A continuous skin temperature of 37 °C does no harm, but if the skin is heated to 50 °C, a burn injury is possible within 2 minutes. If skin temperature rises slowly and continuously, there is no alarm to the brain.

If you place a hand dummy with a temperature sensor and the heater within a glove closed at the wrist and watch the temperature rise over about an hour, you get an idea of the heater effect.

It seems to be difficult to find a heater power that is safe as well as comfortable.
If the unpleasant feeling of very cold hands is not reduced within about five minutes, the impatient wearer would think the heater is useless. A heater that is able to change the feeling from very cold to comfortable warm within 5 to 10 minutes could be dangerous if applied for 30 to 60 minutes, especially without a temperature limiter to less than 37 °C.